# Force refresh (re-scan) wireless networks from command line?

Tags: windows, command-line, wifi

in my program i use command " netsh wlan SHOW NETWORKS MODE=BSSID" to show the available SSID and pass them into my program , the problem is the command don't refresh the available network list it's just show the cash of the last scanning  and i need to re-scan Immediately when i told the program i found some thing disable then re-enable the interface through the netsh commands , and it's work for while , but i update the program now and i need to re-scan when i already connect to some network if i re-scan by this way , I'll disconnecting to this network at least 2 sec, i need another solution please

Answer (score 0):

Ahmed,
if you haven't solved this problem yet, i think, i can help you.
I have the same issue and I found a solution, kind of.
It is possible to refresh, by clicking the wifi-symbol in the right-bottom corner of your computer. Here is a screenshot of this symbol.
[image: Show the symbol]
It will take one or two seconds and then it's refreshed.

I hope I could help you and if you have found a better solution by now,
 it would be nice to let me know.
Greetings, Max

Comment: I think the person who asked this question wanted to initiate the scan programmatically/automatically.

Comment: Yes, sounds resonable, but I have googled for an solution for ours, but I have nothing yet :(

Comment: it may have used to work, but doesn't anymore. It took about 30 sec before my AP was shown